# MongoDB querying with Java API

Tags: java, mongodb, api, mongodb-query

Here is the sample document of my MongoDB:

```
user:{
_id:1,
name:'xyz',
age:12,
mobile:21321312,
transaction:[{
trans_id:1,
prod:'a',
purchasedAt:ISODate("2015-02-01"),
},
{
trans_id:2,
prod:'b',
purchasedAt:ISODate("2015-02-01")
},
{
trans_id:3,
prod:'c',
purchasedAt:ISODate("2014-11-24")
}]
,...
}
```

My query looks like:

```
db.user.find({transaction:{$elemMatch:{prod:'a', purchasedAt:ISODate("2015-02-01")}}, transaction:{$elemMatch:{prod:{$nin:['b','c']}, purchasedAt:ISODate("2015-02-01")}}}).count()
```

I am trying to get the user count who have purchased product 'a' on date "2015-02-01" but not have purchased product b & c on same day.

So while trying to do this in Java with the query:

```
coll.find(new BasicDBObject().append("transaction", new BasicDBObject("$elemMatch", new BasicDBObject("prod", 'a').append("purchasedAt", Date))).append("transaction", new BasicDBObject("$elemMatch", new BasicDBObject("prod", new BasicDBObject("$nin",['b','c'])).append("purchasedAt", Date)));
```

I have also tried:

```
coll.find(new BasicDBObject("transaction", new BasicDBObject("$elemMatch", new BasicDBObject("prod", 'a').append("purchasedAt", Date))).append("transaction", new BasicDBObject("$elemMatch", new BasicDBObject("prod", new BasicDBObject("$nin",['b','c'])).append("purchasedAt", Date)));
```

where `Date` is "2015-02-01" in `util.Date` object.

I found out that Java ignores the `$in` part of the query, i.e. it ignores `{transaction:{$elemMatch:{prod:'a', purchasedAt:ISODate("2015-02-01")}}` & performs only `$nin` part.

> I found out it by DBCursor object.

Here's the output of the cursor:

```
Cursor: Cursor id=0, ns=mydb.user, query={ "transaction" : { "$elemMatch" : { "prod" : { "$nin" : [ "b" , "c"]} , "purchasedAt" : { "$date" : "2015-02-01T00:00:00.000Z"}}}}, numIterated=0, readPreference=primary
```

Because of this my result is inaccurate. I wonder why the exact same query works well in Mongo shell but doesn't with Java API. Is there anything wrong with my query structure?

Comment: you should be able to use `toString()` on your `BasicDBObject` to see what query it is generating. And of course it ignores the first part, because this is a `Map`, and you use the `transaction` key twice. Though the second one overrides the first one.

Comment: `toString()` output is also same as the cursor object. `Query: { "transaction" : { "$elemMatch" : { "prod" : { "$nin" : [ "b" , "c"]} , "purchasedAt" : { "$date" : "2015-02-01T00:00:00.000Z"}}}}`

Comment: See the 2nd part of my comment: `BasicDBObject` is a `Map`.

Comment: Thanks, That was useful. But how can I make Java query both the parts? Is there any other method through which I can query? I am not able to figure out this for the query structure I have.

Comment: You could simply use the `$and` operator ( http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/and/ ) and inside there you put you two `transaction` queries. This should work.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that this question is now moot, but, if you still do not consider it answered, are you looking for the "$not" operator, which can check for non-existance sort of.